# onKey listner works properly on emulator, but not working on android device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm working on a android project in which i need to change a table layout according to the changes on a **edit text view**. The code work properly on **emulator**. But it doesn't works on actual **device**. Also in this case I'm using fragments. My **onKey** listener is  as below.

```
EditProduct.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Editable prx=EditProduct.getText();

            String new_prx=prx.toString();

            //mini_productList
            int count=0;
            if (new_prx.equals("")) {

                loadtableProducts(productList);

            }else {

                for(int i=0;i<productList.size();i++){

                    if (productList.get(i).getDescription().toString().substring(0, (new_prx.length())).equalsIgnoreCase(new_prx)) {

                        mini_productList.add(productList.get(i));
                        count++;

                    }

                }

                loadtableProducts(mini_productList);

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No of products "+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also the edit text view in my **layout** is as below

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_product"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/txtWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/txtHeight"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:hint="Enter the product name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/boldtext" />
```

Also i added a Toast to make sure its work on the device and it shown on the entering of a key.
So can someone help me in this matter.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for EditText.setOnKeyListener states:

"Register a callback to be invoked when a hardware key is pressed in this view. Key presses in software input methods will generally not trigger the methods of this listener."

The emulator is using a hardware keyboard whereas your device is using a software keyboard. I suggest you use an "addTextChangedListener" as an alternative.

However I note that you say that your Toast does indicate the entering of a key. So are you actually entering your OnKeyListener when using the actual device? If so, I will delete my answer.

Comment: no, it just shows the toast. but not changes the table. I'll try your one.

Comment: Oh i was forgot to leave a comment. I used **afterTextChanged** inside the **onTextChanged** listener. It worked properly. Thanks in advance.